# Is there a way to handle Amazaon S3 credentials through environment variables in Teradata TPT script

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, teradata

I am setting up my terdata TPT script with S3 and want to use environment file variable in TPT script for amazon S3 credentials instead of hardcode Access key, accessId & region.

Any thoughts?

```
DEFINE JOB EXPORT_FROM_TERADATA DESCRIPTION 'Export data from Teradata to Amazon S3' 

( STEP EXPORT_THE_DATA 
        ( APPLY TO OPERATOR 
                ( $FILE_WRITER() ATTR 
                             ( AccessModuleName = 'libs3axsmod.so',Format = 'Delimited' , AccessModuleInitStr = 'S3Bucket=nn-model-sagemaker-test S3Region=eu-west-1 S3Object=tpt/testdata S3SinglePartFile=False S3AccessID=AKIZZZZZZZZZZZZZZU S3AccessKey=kxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx7' ) 
                 ) 
                 SELECT * FROM OPERATOR ( $EXPORT ATTR ( UserName = @TargetUserName , UserPassword = @TargetUserPassword, TdpId = @TargetTdpId , SelectStmt = 'SELECT TOP 10 * FROM database.table;' ) ); 
         ); 
);
```

Hardcoded credentials are working in TPT script but variables aren't.

```
( AccessModuleName = 'libs3axsmod.so',Format = 'Delimited' ,
 AccessModuleInitStr = 'S3Bucket=@model-test S3Region=S3AXMS3Region S3AccessID=S3AXMS3AccessID S3AccessKey=S3AXMS3AccessKey' )
```

Comment: have you tried this yet: https://pypi.org/project/aws-profile/ . This utility injects AWS creds into your ENV variables for your command.

Answer (score 1):

You can't access environment variables within a TPT script, but you can use the -u switch on the command line to have the shell pass the values of environment variables as TPT script variables.

```
tbuild -f scriptfile -u "S3Rgn='$S3AXMS3Region' …"
```

And you can use string concatenation to create an AccessModuleInitStr

```
AccessModuleInitStr='S3Bucket='''||@model-test||''' S3Region='''||@S3Rgn||''' … '
```

Note that you could get the AccessID and AccessKey from a credentials file and Region from a config file (and just specify the corresponding S3Profile in the Init String).

Answer (score 0):

In case your export/import job is running in AWS cloud, you can use `IAM roles`, which are effectively short lived credentials.

You can attach an IAM role (instance profile) to an EC2 instance, ECS task, Lambda, etc. with necessary permissions. `s3:*` will do for starters, but can be reduced further to:

- `s3:ListAllMyBuckets`
- `s3:GetBucketLocation`
- `s3:ListBucket`
- `s3:GetObject`
- `s3:PutObject`
- `s3:DeleteObject`

AWS will automatically rotate these credentials, and `tbuild` will pick them up.

**test.tpt**

```
DEFINE JOB EXPORT_FROM_TERADATA DESCRIPTION 'Export data from Teradata to Amazon S3' (
    STEP EXPORT_DATA (
        APPLY TO OPERATOR (
            $FILE_WRITER() ATTR (
                AccessModuleName = 'libs3axsmod.so',
                Format = 'Delimited'
            )
        )
        SELECT * FROM OPERATOR (
            $EXPORT ATTR (
                LogonMech = 'ldap',
                UserName = @TargetUserName ,
                UserPassword = @TargetUserPassword,
                TdpId = @TargetDbIp,
                SelectStmt = 'SELECT 10 * FROM @TargetDatabase.@TargetTable;'
            )
        );
    );
);
```

**test.env**

```
TargetDbIp = '10.11.12.13',
TargetUserName = 'dbuser',
TargetUserPassword = '**********',
TargetDatabase = 'database',
TargetTable = 'table',
FileWriterAccessModuleInitStr = 'S3Bucket=my-lovely-bucket S3Region=eu-central-1 S3Object=folder/file.csv S3SinglePartFile=True S3Role=MyIAMRole'
```

Then run tbuild from e.g. your EC2, ECS task, Kubernetes pod, Lambda, etc.:

```
$ tbuild -f test.tpt -v test.env
```

This will export data from Teradata’s  `database.table` table into `s3://my-lovely-bucket/folder/file.csv` in the `eu-central-1` region.

You can find `tbuild` documentation [here](https://docs.teradata.com/r/p%7E0sSD4zl4K8YPbEGnM3Rg/HIpKTAzSRGV_h%7EZCN0PWVg).